# Checking variable in database via php (if statements)

Tags: php, mysql, database

So after a long rest of coding(around 5months) i started to forgot some of the codes and i need help with this one, i cant find in the google with this topic, etc

[image]

code :

```
<?php

$num1 = "0";

$database = mysql_connect('x', 'x', 'x') or die ("Error x01");
mysql_select_db('x') or die ("Error x02");

$SQL1 = "Select * FROM 'server_status' WHERE on = '$num1'";
$result_id1 = @mysql_query($SQL1) or die("DATABASE ERROR!");
$total1 = mysql_num_rows($result_id1);

if($result1){
   echo "Server is under maintenance";
}

?>
```

right here i have a code where i'am gonna check the variable "on" in "server_status" table in my msql
[image]

somehow even when i have my "on" variable on 0 (int not bool [join_protection is on int too]) it still gives out the die which is

```
or die ("DATABASE ERROR!");
```

i can't find how to fix that i played around with it and not managed to make it work

here's the result
[image]

i'm looking forward for your answer
thanks for passing by and helping me

regards,
-itsproinc

Comment: can you please post text-based code and not an image of. This poses a problem and for a few reasons.

Comment: plus, this doesn't help you `or die ("DATABASE ERROR!");` this does `mysql_error()` and remove the `@` in `@mysql_query` it's an error suppressor.

Comment: yest thats the problem im trying to bypass the "or die" since it gives the correct value why would it show "or die"

Comment: I posted an answer for you below.

Comment: Actually, I spotted another issue, and I've made an additional edit to my answer in regards to your column name `on`. Do reload it if you've seen the first copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single quotes which are not the correct [Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) around your table name, remove them.

```
FROM server_status
```

or use ticks: (which resemble quotes, but are not the same).

```
FROM `server_status`
```

Plus, you are using a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), being `on` for your column name and it needs to be wrapped in ticks.

```
$SQL1 = "Select * FROM `server_status` WHERE `on` = '$num1'";
```

Plus, as I stated in comments:

This doesn't help you `or die ("DATABASE ERROR!");` this does [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) and remove the `@` in `@mysql_query` it's an error suppressor.

---

Deprecation notice:

`mysql_` is deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

Use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Better yet:

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: Thankyou, ill start using and learning mysqli_, thanks man i appreciate it :D